# Ajax response returns wrong response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

There is an Ajax request by `GET` method in my website. There is an inbox of incoming messages, number of unread messages is written some where, once the user read an unread message, I update the number of unread messages using an Ajax request to the server to get the new one.

The problem is, number of unread messages is right in server side, but the Ajax response is not what server says after reading a few on unread messages. For example if there are `4` unread messages, when I click on a message, it becomes `3`, when I click on another unread message, it will be `3` again not `2` while when I look at server response directly in browser (the request is GET), it is `2` not `3`. So I am sure the server side is right but the Ajax response is not.

This is my code, some Laravel codes are inside it to specify the route. the Ajax request with comment `//this is request to unread message` has problem.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            cache: false
        });

        $(document).on('click', '.messageOutline .card-header', function () {
            var url = '{{route('messages.loadMessage', ":id")}}';
            url = url.replace(":id", $(this).parent().parent().attr('id'));
            $.get(url).done(function (data) {
                $("#messageColumn").html(data);
            });
            if($(this).hasClass('text-primary')){
                $(this).removeClass('text-primary').addClass('text-dark');
                var url = '{{route('messages.unreadMessages', ":id")}}';
                url = url.replace(":id", $(this).attr('id').substring(16));
                var id = $(this).attr('id').substring(16);
                $.get({url:url}).done(function (data) {//this is request to unread messages
                    alert("sent" + data);
                    if(data == 0)
                        $("#user-"+id).find('.count').remove();
                    else{
                        $("#user-"+id).find('.count').html(data);
                    }

                });
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(url)` to see what your URL looks like? What does your network tab show in your browser; is the request getting through?

Comment: @Soviut Like I said the server is right. the `url` is right and I already tried that.

Comment: So you're saying it goes from 4 to 3 and then sticks to 3 indefinitely? Is the `alert` displaying 3 as well? There is no reason for `jQuery.get` to return anything else but the result of the request you see on your Network tab.

Comment: @Jeto no. it shows `3` twice then `1`

Comment: @Jeto I guess it may be a sort of caching

Comment: Please try and make a reproducible sample then, and edit your question with it. You can use https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/ to make fake ajax requests.

Comment: @Jeto I solved the problem and posted it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by the following changes

```
        $(document).on('click', '.messageOutline .card-header', function () {
            $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
            var url = '{{route('messages.loadMessage', ":id")}}';
            url = url.replace(":id", $(this).parent().parent().attr('id'));
            var object = $(this);
            $.get(url).done(function (data) {
                $("#messageColumn").html(data);
                if(object.hasClass('text-primary')){
                    object.removeClass('text-primary').addClass('text-dark');
                    var url = '{{route('messages.unreadMessages', ":id")}}';
                    var id = object.attr('id').substring(16);
                    url = url.replace(":id", id);
                    $.get({url:url, cache: false}).done(function (data) {
                        if(data == 0)
                            $("#user-"+id).find('.count').remove();
                        else{
                            $("#user-"+id).find('.count').html(data);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        })
```

I moved the second Ajax request to the success function of the first one. In this way I am sure the number of unread messages are taken after reading a message and updating its `read` property in the database.